# Segmentation fault when calling vector.erase()

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

Whenever I call `dominoes.erase()` which is of type `std::vector<Domino>` I get a segmentation fault; even if I hard code the value.

A separate member function calls `dominoes.push_back()` to load data and I'm able to use `pop_back()` to remove and return the a domino from the vector, so I know there's data in there. I've got a copy constructor made on the Domino object and that works just fine. I've narrowed it down to `dominoes.erase()`.

```
Domino::Domino( const Domino &d ) {
    left = d.getHighPip();
    right = d.getLowPip();

}
Domino DominoCollection::drawDomino( void )
{

    int index = random.nextNumber( dominoes.size()  );
    Domino d( dominoes[index] );
    dominoes.erase( dominoes.begin() + index );

    return Domino( d );
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you post code for random.nextNumber ?

Comment: Also, the way `Domino` is implemented can influence things

Comment: Given a correct copy constructor and a valid index, this should work just fine. You can just say `return d;`, btw.

Comment: Are you sure that `index < dominoes.size()` ?

Comment: If `index` >= `dominoes.size()` you end up erasing past the end of the container.

Comment: Even if I hard-code it to 0 it fails. @sehe I put the copy constructor in for reference. Any idea?

Comment: How do you initialize the dominoes vector?

Comment: @VictorSand I don't initialize it, it's defined as a member object and I use `push_back()` to insert elements into it.

Comment: If you supply an index of 0 and it still segfaults then either the destructor of `Domino` is doing something wrong or your container is empty.

Comment: Does your `Domino` class violate the Rule of Zero?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious `domino.size()` is larger than zero at the time erase is called. I have not declared `Domino::~Domino()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to narrow down the error by removing all unnecessary code (object copy, vector access...). Then if the problem really comes from `erase`, add guards to be sure the indexes are right. Try again with this code:

```
#include <cassert>
void DominoCollection::drawDomino( void )
{
    assert(dominoes.size() != 0 && "Your vector is empty");
    int index = random.nextNumber( dominoes.size()  );
    assert(index < dominoes.size() && "Buffer overflow...");
    dominoes.erase( dominoes.begin() + index );
}
```

If it still segfaults, the problem comes from the destructor of the class `Domino`. Look if there is anything fishy there. You can do quick tests by commenting parts of the destructor (or all of it), to know where the problem comes from. Calling `erase` will call the destructor of `Domino`.

If the destructor is not implemented, it might be a good idea to implement one with an output in it (on `cerr`, not `cout`) to know if it gets there or crashes earlier on. Is `Domino` a derived class? Does it have any other objects in it or only a composition of primitive types?

**Edit**

I went through your code quickly: the problem comes from the assignment operator:

```
Domino & Domino::operator = ( const Domino & d )
{
    *this = d;
}
```

This is **NOT** how it should be written... I let you debug that as an exercise.

As for why that is the source of the bug: you said `erase` crashed but not `pop_back`. The main difference between the two (implementation difference, not the obvious semantic difference) is that erasing causes all the elements to shift after the ones deleted (using the `=` operator) because `std::vector` requires the elements to be stored consecutively. Whereas pop just changes the tail pointer and does not alter the rest of the container.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Great idea. Unfortunately it still segfaults on `dominoes.erase()` despite passing the assertions :(

Comment: The destructor class of `Domino` isn't implemented.

Comment: I created ~Domino() and output a message on `cerr`. Based on that, it doesn't appear to be getting to the destructor of `Domino` at all. `Domino` is a base class.

Comment: Please try the function in my reply.

Comment: It crashes at `vd.erase(vd.begin());`

Comment: solved, i let you fix it yourself, it is more satisfactory that way ;)

Answer (score 0):

From what you show us, it looks like the `int index` has a value greater than or equal to `dominoes.size()`. Otherwise, that code would work just fine.

I'd check what `random.NextNumber(dominoes.size())` returns.

Also, this problem could occur if `dominoes.size() == 0`. In that case, you'd be erasing `dominoes.end()`.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately that's not it. Even hardcoding it to a value I know is there causes it to fault on `erase()`.